# Clipping raster objects in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, shapefile, r

I'm trying to cutting a raster object (from a PostGIS table) using a shapefile with reference, extracting raster data from a polygon area. My objective  to work with the  clipping raster into R.

I'm cutting in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE clippingtable as (SELECT (ST_Union(ST_Clip(raster.rast, ST_Transform(polygon.geom, ST_SRID(raster.rast) ) ) ) )
  FROM originalraster as raster, originalshape as polygon
  WHERE ST_Intersects(raster.rast, polygon.geom))
```

The gdalinfo output is:

```
$gdalinfo "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='testdb' schema='public' table=clippingtable"
ERROR 1: Error retrieving raster metadata
gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname='testdb' schema='public' table=clippingtable'.
```

In R I'm using these functions:

```
dsn="PG:dbname=testdb host=localhost port=5432 table=clippingtable"
rgdal::GDALinfo(dsn)
readGDAL(dsn)
```

The output is:
"Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Error retrieving raster metadata"

In original table (before cutting) I can work normally with my raster.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like maybe rgdal relies on raster_columns metadata for info.   http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_AddRasterConstraints.html

Try running this:

```
SELECT AddRasterConstraints('clippingtable'::name, 'st_union'::name);
```

I should add that I'm guessing your raster column is called st_union since you didn't explicitly name it with

```
As rast
```

You should explicitly name it to keep your sanity.

Even after you do this, it's possible rgdal will still complain since as I recall early versions of GDAL would not work with non-rectangular, non-even blocked.  rasters which a clipped version is likely to be

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the column name in my raster object, and the output in my R program was different. See:

PG:dbname=testdb host=localhost table=clippingtable has GDAL driver PostGISRaster and has 0 rows and 0 columns
Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “GridTopology” object: cells.dim has incorrect dimension
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In dim(x) : no bands in dataset
2: In dim(x) : no bands in dataset

I didn't understand well the objective of the function AddRasterConstraints in my case,  should I use it?
Thanks

Comment: Well as a recall gdal tries to query the raster_columns view.  That view reads the constraints from the table.  Calling that function will add constraints like dim sizes to the table.

Comment: Thank you so much. The constrains was added with the AddRasterConstraints function. Problem solved.